# how to remove create relation foreign key in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having problems in PhpMyAdmin Designer Section. I'm not able to do anything like I cant even move them to see their relations. When I try to click on tables the screen shown in picture appear with the "create relation" message while I already created their relations. This happening to all my databases. Any help???
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5thdl.png)

Comment: i think there is an issue with javascript in designer in phpmyadmin and you can't work. Try a quick sql dump of that database and check to see that all relations are there.

Comment: Try navigating to Database: phpmyadmin->table pma__designer_settings. Do you get an error message?

Comment: i don't see any errors